# Getting a -23 stringindexoutofboundsexception

Tags: java

In my driver I have a try catch and I'm getting an a -23 `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. when I use this line in my driver:

```
DbEntry dbe = new DbEntry(dabaLine);
```

`dabaLine` is a simple line with the content:

> :Mr:Wilburforce:Gates:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DbEntry {

    private String entry;
    private ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    public DbEntry(String entry){
        this.entry = entry;
        fields = new ArrayList<>();
        int y = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        while(entry.indexOf(':', y) != -1){
            counter++;
            String z = "";
            String subString = "";
            x = entry.indexOf(":", y);
            y = entry.indexOf(":", x+1);
            z = entry.substring(x+1, y);
            fields.add(z);
            System.out.println(z);
            System.out.print(counter);
        }

    }

    public String getValue(int fieldNumber){ //throws and indexOutOfBoundsException
        return fields.get(fieldNumber-1);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.entry;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the exception?

Comment: When I use DbEntry dbe = new DbEntry(dabaLine); in my driver

Comment: Which line in the constructor?

Comment: Also what is your input line?

Comment: Mentioned above already, the value passing through label is  :Mr:Wilburforce:Gates:

Comment: It goes through everything, but when it finishes it comes back as -23 stringindexoutofboundsexception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this:

```
y = entry.indexOf(":", x+1);
z = entry.substring(x+1, y);
```

If there is no ":" after `x+1` then y will be `-1`, and then the next call to `entry.substring` will fail.

The method substring checks if the second value is less than the first value and throws an exception with the difference. That's why you get a strange number in the exception.

To fix it, you can check if y is -1 like so:

```
y = entry.indexOf(":", x+1);
if (y == -1)
    break;
z = entry.substring(x+1, y);
```

Comment: But it will fail with a value of -1, not -23, right? Or am I overlooking something here?

Comment: No because the method substring will fail internally because it checks if the second value is less than the first value and throws an exception with the difference.

Comment: So how should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Test if y is -1 before the `substring` call? I'm not entirely sure what your input is, so I can't be sure.